# java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed. when use MediaRecord#stop

Tags: java, android

here is my [full code](https://gist.github.com/618198030c2ad459ad85f8961d59b6b1), here is [my project](https://github.com/roroco/adr-try/tree/MediaRecorder#stop-faield), when i use MediaRecorder#stop in #onCreate, it raise

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
at ro.rotry.TestMr.onCreate(TestMr.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

so how to fix it?

Comment: you have'nt use setaudiosource()  and setaudioencoder()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is i miss #createVirtualDisplay before #start, here is my full activity

```
package ro.rotry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMr extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaRecorder mr;
    MediaProjection mp;
    int dw = 720;
    int dh = 1280;
    MediaProjectionManager mpm;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_mr);
        mr = new MediaRecorder();
        initRecorder();
        mpm = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        startActivityForResult(mpm.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mp = mpm.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mp.createVirtualDisplay(getClass().getName(), dw, dh, metrics.densityDpi, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mr.getSurface(), new Callback(), null);
        mr.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        mr.stop();
    }

    class Callback extends VirtualDisplay.Callback {

    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        try {

            mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mr.setOutputFile(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                            .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4");
            mr.setVideoSize(dw, dh);
            mr.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mr.setVideoEncodingBitRate(12 * 1000 * 1000);
            mr.setVideoFrameRate(60);
            mr.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you code and it doesn't work, I get error with `mr.stop();` - `E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007` on Redmi 4 Prime (Marshmallow, 6 Android)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
    mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mr.setVideoSize(1920, 1080);
    mr.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

try using camcorder profile:

```
        try {

        camera.unlock();

        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        recorder.setCamera(camera);

        recorder.setOrientationHint(cameraRotationDegree);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(5000000);
        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir() + "/try.mp4");
        recorder.prepare();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        recorder.start();

     }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't fix my question, camera doesn't capture android screen(like gameplay)

Comment: camera capture and screen recording are different things